# Regex with negative lookahead is not working

Tags: javascript, regex, text

```
Edit the Expression & Text to see matches.

Expression sample
```

This is the text document which has two lines. I want to search for "Expression" word such that it does not follow "matches" word. So the output will be match to "Expression sample" line.
Please help to generate regex for this. I have tried using following regex but this is not working. Many thanks

```
^(.*)Expression(.*)(?!matches)$
```

Comment: Use `/Expression(?!.*matches)/`

Comment: Looks like you want to match lines with `Expression` word in them but with no `matches`. Try `/^(?!.*\bmatches\b).*\bExpression\b.*/gm`

Answer (score 2):

In your same the regex will match the following:

```
 Edit the Expression & Text to see matches.
^(.*     )Expression(.*                   )(?!matches)$
```

As you can see, the second `.*` has consumes the rest of the string, thus meaning the lookahead will not match (because there are no more characters), and the end-of-line anchor matches.

To codify the requirement that `matches` may not appear anywhere after `Expression` you need to use

```
Expression(?!.*matches)
```

instead. Optionally with `(.*)` pre- and postfixed if you desperately need them. This regex essentially means that `Expression` *has to match* somewhere, while the whole sub-expression `.*matches` *must not* match after the `Expression` match. Since that sub-expression includes `.*` it will try matching `matches` anywhere after that and if it matches even only once, the lookahead fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
/Expression(?!.*matches)/
```

Is the answer. Thanks  anubhava for helping me.